# How to bind color inside windows resource in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have custom tab control, where colors are given in

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="TabControl_BackgroundColor_Base" >Blue</Color>
        .......
 </Window.Resources>
```

How to bind color=Blue to DynamicResource. 
So Blue can be Brown,Red,White,Green depends on user's choice.

By saying this, I mean users can change color. Now I am writing as Blue here. I want it to be dynamic, for example I am giving dynamic color to background of my windows in my application.

```
Background="{DynamicResource DynamicBG}"
```

Is there any way to do this task without changing much code?

Comment: Not clear " How to give to this dynamic color as I am giving it to my window such as" , explain elaborately

Comment: Now I am writing Red inside color, I want to give it dynamic color, color can be changed by users.

Comment: While I understand that English is *not* your first language, you *really* do need to do better than that to be understood. Please clearly explain what are you asking for?

Comment: @Sheridan I think, I explained it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done using XAML and code behind. First, in XAML add control (e.g. ComboBox named `cmbColor`) to select the color and populate it with all colors you have mentioned. Second, in code behind ad the event handle for that ComboBox as shown below:

```
cmbColor.SelectrionChanged+=()=>
{
     // assign color to your win or main grid background using switch statement
     switch(cmbColor.Text)
     {
         case "Blue":  gridMain.Background = Brushes.Blue; break;
         case "Green":  gridMain.Background = Brushes.Green; break;
         default: break;
      }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add all colors to win ResourceDictionary (or even create a Theme per each) that user can select.

Rgds,

Comment: I have done it already, using Combobox. I can change background color of my application, but I can not change color of Tab Item. Because I am hardly writing it here <Color x:Key="TabControl_BackgroundColor_Base" >Blue</Color>

Comment: Then you should apply dynamic formatting to this control as well, using similar technique. Rgds,

Comment: I have added the sample code snippet for colors Blue and Green: you can extend it for any other color. Please mark the answer accepted. Rgds,

Comment: Where is the `IValueConverter`? http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/useful-calue-converters